# Xlinq query returning null WhereEnumerableIterator<>

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

i'm trying to do a filtering xlinq query in c# 4.0, so i can bind to a DataContext. the code is this:

```
public IEnumerable<XElement> Filter(int min = 0, int max = int.MaxValue)
{
    IEnumerable<XElement> selected = (
        from x in xmlFile.Elements("Product")
        where (int)x.Element("Price") >= min &&
              (int)x.Element("Price") <= max
        select x);

    return selected;
}
```

xmlFile is an XElement with an external xml file loaded. the xml file structure looks something like this:

```
<Stock>
    <Product>
      <Name /> 
      <Price /> 
      <Quantity /> 
    </Product>
    ...
</Stock>
```

I don't get any errors when building or running, but the `selected` variable gets only null (even without the where clause). When I hover the mouse over the variable when debugging, it shows the type System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator. If I just return the xmlFile, it goes fine, but I really need to do the filtering!

---

EDIT

as far as I've researched, the problem is on the "xmlFile.Elements("Product")" statement. I don't know how to explain this, so I made a screenshot (in my code I actually use "Respuesto" in place of "Products", I translated it here to make it easier):

(It won't let me insert an image because i'm a new user, but it es here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTt8r.png

I use this function in my code as a DataContext like this:

```
gridpricelist.DataContext = Conn.Filter(min: Convert.ToInt32(minprice.Text),
                            max: Convert.ToInt32(maxprice.Text));
```

minprice and maxprice are textboxes, and a KeyUp event triggers the function from above

---

EDIT2

I figured it out, see my answer. But I can't explain why it works that way, could someone help me understand?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give a short but *complete* example showing the problem. I can imagine the return value being *empty*, but not *null*. In particular, if it's showing the type as WhereEnumerableIterator then it's clearly *not* null!

Comment: @tinchou: `Current` is `null` because it hasn't been enumerated yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out! Although I don't know why the Xlinq approach doesn't work... here is the code that worked for me instead of the query:

```
    public XElement filter(int min = 0, int max = int.MaxValue)
    {            
        XElement filtered = new XElement("Stock");
        foreach (XElement product in xmlFile.Elements("Product"))
        {
            if ((int)product.Element("Price") >= min &&
                (int)product.Element("Price") <= max)
                    filtered.Add(product);
        }
        return filtered;
    }
```

that would be great if someone gives me an explain. thanks for reading

Comment: What you were seeing in the debugger is *normal* because the LINQ query had not been enumerated yet. And your binding failed because you did not wrap it in the `Stock` XElement.

Answer (score 2):

If you have "empty" or "not existing" price elements it will break

Try this:

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> Filter(int min = 0, int max = int.MaxValue)
{
    Func<XElement, int?> parse = p => {
        var element = p.Element("Price");

        if (element == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int value;

        if (!Int32.TryParse(element.Value, out value)) {
            return null;
        }

        return value;
    };

    IEnumerable<XElement> selected = (
        from x in xmlFile.Elements("Product")
        let value = parse(x)
        where value >= min &&
            value <= max
        select x);

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Hi, "Element("Stock")" isn't right because I use an XElement in xmlFile, not XDocument. So I don't have to put the root, Stock. I figured out that the "Elements("Product")" statement is failing, it returns a null System.Xml.Linq.XContainer. Something on your mind? And thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

1. When you hovered over the `WhereEnumerableIterator` and saw `.Current` was `null`, everything was working normally. [This is *deferred execution* at work.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx) Some LINQ queries (this applies to XLinq too) do not execute until you enumerate them, hence `.Current` will be `null` until you use it! When you used `foreach` in your answer it enumerated the iterator and produced a value.
2. Your initial code did not work as it returned an enumeration of XML without a root element, and it appears whatever your calling code is it required it to have a root. Your answer wraps the data in a `<Stock>` element. You can use your original code like so:

   ```
   public XElement Filter(int min = 0, int max = int.MaxValue)
   {
       var selected = (
           from x in xmlFile.Elements("Product")
           where (int)x.Element("Price") >= min &&
                 (int)x.Element("Price") <= max
           select x);

       return new XElement("Stock", selected);
   }
   ```